# Call same function no matter what function is called in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm not exactly sure what I should Title this, but here's my use case.

Currently I've been building some special objects like so:

```js
test = function() {
  function _MESSAGE(func, name) {
    jQuery("#log").append(func + ' ' + name+'\n');
  }
  this.hello = {
    push: function(name) {
      _MESSAGE('hello', name);
    }
  }
  this.goodbye = {
    push: function(name) {
      _MESSAGE('goodbye', name);
    }
  }
}

var message = new test();

message.hello.push('Will'); //Returns: hello Will
message.goodbye.push('Will'); //Returns: goodbye Will
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

*This is just an example though, and not exactly what it's being used for.*

I would like to be able to make message.*.push send to _MESSAGE no matter what the name is. If you'd try that now, it would tell you that message.whatever is undefined.

I don't want to do `message('howdy', 'Will');`

I want `message.howdy.push('Will')` to work.

Is this type of thing even possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible in JavaScript. There's no mechanism that'd allow you to "catch" undefined property references.

Comment: Not without Proxies from ES6 at least.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, i wouldn't have even know how to search for that.

Comment: @ethree: I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=catch+undefined+property) - but I knew that such a duplicate did exist :-)